# accessing getRelatedDocuments from within docpad.coffee

Tags: coffeescript, docpad

Any suggestion on how to access **@getRelatedDocuments()** directly from within inner function. Only way I could get my snippet to work was as below where **@getRelatedDocuments()** is assigned to a variable outside of inner. docpad throws error stating that it is unable to access **@getRelatedDocuments()** function if I place it inside the **inner** function

```
getRelatedWidget: (widgetName) ->               
    documents = @getRelatedDocuments()          
    inner = ->
        res = for relPost in documents
        """
                <li><a href="#{relPost.url}">#{relPost.title}</a></li>"""
                return res.join('')

    outer = -> """
        <aside id="related-posts">
            <h3 class="widget-title">#{widgetName}</h3>
                <nav class="linklist">
            <ul>
                #{inner()}
            </ul>                   
            </nav>
        </aside>
        """ 
        if @getRelatedDocuments().length
            outer()
```

I'd like to rather use:

```
inner = ->
    res = for relPost in @getRelatedDocuments()
        .....
```

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

Make it an argument.

```
inner = (related_docs) ->
  res = for relPost in related_docs
    ...

outer = -> """
  <aside id="related-posts">
    <h3 class="widget-title">#{widgetName}</h3>
      <nav class="linklist">
        <ul>
          #{inner(@ getRelatedDocuments())}
        </ul>                   
      </nav>
  </aside>
  """
```

Comment: That would look better if the call to inner(@getRelatedDocuments()) would work, it suffers form the same issue. 

Seeing as the call to @getRelatedDocuments is within a nested function (function outer, which is nested under getRelatedWidget: (widgetName) ->), compiler throws same error stating that getRelatedDocuments is not defined.